# primefaces treetable checkbox selection set selected minus sign

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

For primefaces treetable, on client side, we can set `node1` as selected by something like:

```
TreeNode node1 = //...
node1.setSelected(true);
```

If this `node1` has a parent `parentNode`, and this parent has other **unselected** children `node2`, `node3`, etc.

In this case, there should be a minus sign in the checkbox beside `parentNode` just like what you will get in the showcase here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTableCheckbox.jsf
. But it's not working.

For the `parentNode`, I also have `setSelected()`, by which I can control whether there will be a check in the checkbox. But there is no option like a `setPartialSelected()` for me to control the minus sign.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!